# Why not giving compilation error?

Tags: scala, object, runtime, traits

I have below piece of code

```
object SubClass extends MyTrait {
  private[this] val a = 10

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println(a)
  }

}

trait MyTrait {
  protected val a = 5

}
```

And it gives following runtime error. Can somebody explain why we didn't catch it in compile time.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate field
>   name&signature in class file SubClass$    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
>   SubClass.main(TraitTest.scala)

Answer (score 2):

Because software has bugs?

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7475

That would be my guess.

The related ticket has received recent attention:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2568